# Why is recovery partition shown in Optimise Drives in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, efi, disk-management, recovery-partition

Since the recovery partition never gets optimised, and probably doesn't have the need to be optimised. Then why does it show up there?

[image: Click]

This is my disk management info :

[image]

Also, if the recovery partition is shown there, then why not the EFI partition?